# I see duplicated components in my Dev Tools in the Source Panel using Vite + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPs2A.jpg)

I'm new to React and I'm using Vite to install it. Everything was working fine until I noticed when I opened my Dev Tools and navigated to the Source Panel and looked for my code, I saw all my components duplicated. I also noticed that they have (from source map) next to it and the other is from localhost.

I'm not sure if this should be the expected behavior or if I am doing something wrong. Can someone explain why is doing that?

I tried to create a new React file with Vite and even the default App has duplicate. I kind of think that this is the way Vite to configured but still wondering if is something wrong on my end

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, always add your code as text, inside ``` not as photos!

Comment: Well, the photo is from the Dev Tools. I'm not sure what code I put because my localhost is not showing duplicates. Only when I open Dev tools and navigate to the Source Panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the cause of the issue. It was actually about the sourcemap that is only available on the localhost. When the website/app is deployed, the duplicates are no longer visible. Although, if you wanna hide them on your Dev Tools you can hide them by uncheck the **"Source Map"** in the Debugger Panel in Mozila Browser from the upper right wheel icon settings.

I haven't tried this on Google Chrome, but I'm assuming is something similar